# Bound of polynomial of degree n with Euclidean norms

Tags: polynomials

Let $p(x), x\in \mathbb{R}^m$ a real-coefficients polynomial of degree $n$, such that $p(x)>0$ for all $x\neq 0$ and $p(0)$ if, and only if $x=0$. I was wondering if, in general, is it possible to find two positive constants $c_1, c_2$ such that 
$$
c_1 \min\{\|x\|,\|x\|^n \} \le p(x) \le c_2 \max\{\|x\|,\|x\|^n \} 
$$
For example, is it possible to find two positive constants $c_1,c_2$ such that the following inequalities holds? 
$$
c_1 \min\{\|x\|,\|x\|^4 \} \le \frac{1}{2}(x_1+x_3)^2+\frac{1}{2}(x_2-x_3^2)^2+x_3^2 \le c_2 \max\{\|x\|,\|x\|^4 \} 
$$

Is so, is there a method to find such constants?

Comment: It is not possible to solve this as stated, as existence of such positive $c_1$ would imply that the only zero of $p$ is for $x = 0$. You probably need to reformulate it somehow.

Comment: I agree. What if I add the condition $p(x)>0$ for all $x \neq 0$ and $p(x)=0$ if, and only if $x=0$? Would that make more sense? If so. should I edit the original question?